# How do I automatically sync/couple an Excel file to Onedrive on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, onedrive, cloud-storage

I know how to save a file on Onedrive and it all works fine. But I would like to couple an Excel-file on my computer (or elsewhere) to Onedrive. That is: I work on a file in Excel and when I save that file, I want it to be both saved on my hard drive but also on Onedrive, with a single "Save"-click. Is that possible?

I am using Mac OS X.

Comment: This behavior is built-in natively to Windows 8.1. What version of Windows are you using? (hint: whenever you ask a question where any information such as Windows version could possibly be useful to people helping you, please remember to include that information in your original post.)

Comment: I'm on Mac so no windows. Is it built in here also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this Microsoft FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/skydrive/mac-app-faq)

> **What does the SkyDrive folder do?**
>   When you install the SkyDrive app for Mac, a copy of your SkyDrive is downloaded to your Mac and put in the SkyDrive folder. This folder is kept in sync with SkyDrive. If you add, change, or delete a file or folder on SkyDrive.com, the file or folder is added, changed, or deleted in your SkyDrive folder and vice versa.

So all you have to do is [download](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/skydrive/download) the SkyDrive app for OS X, and store your Excel file in the SkyDrive folder. Couldn't possibly be simpler.

Comment: You're the man. I'll try it tomorrow.